# FileDepot sql errors

Tags: 7

I have recently installed drupal6 and filedepot. Things were working ok, but I was getting some errors come through so I patched it with this http://drupal.org/files/issues/filedepot-group-by.patch

But now I am getting these errors

```
warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "REGEXP" LINE 1: ...FROM nextag_items WHERE type='filedepot' AND tags REGEXP '(^... ^ in /usr/share/drupal6/includes/database.pgsql.inc on line 139.
user warning: query: SELECT itemid FROM nextag_items WHERE type='filedepot' AND tags REGEXP '(^|,)1(,|$)' in /etc/drupal/6/sites/default/modules/filedepot/nexcloud.class.php on line 504.
```

Any one know any thing about them. Or know of a better document managment system for drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using postgres instead of mysql, AFAIK postgres doesn't support REGEXP.

As an alternative you can look at [atrium_folders](http://nuvole.org/blog/2011/may/25/apps-open-atrium-atrium-folders) but it has not as many features as filedepot and it needs [open atrium](http://openatrium.com/).